# Bind to right-click with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to bind a function to a right click. Is this possible with jQuery UI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

though not listed on http://api.jquery.com/bind/, the 'contextmenu' event seems to work

```
$('.rightclickable').bind('contextmenu', function() {
    // right-click!
});
```

Comment: bind is deprecated. You should use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) now.

Answer (score 7):

Not directly, but you can check which mouse button was pressed in a normal `mousedown` event handler, with the [`which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) property of the event object:

```
$("#someElem").mousedown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 3) {
        //Right click!
    }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/vagEa/) of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        //your
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).bind('contextmenu',function(){
    return false;
});
$.fn.extend({
    "rightClick": function(fn){
        $(this).mousedown(function(e){
            if (3 == e.which) {
                fn();
            }
        });
    }
});
$(function(){
    $('selector').rightClick(function(){
        // defined your right click event here!
    });
});
```